# Java Memory Segments

Tags: java, memory-segmentation

I am very confused with Java Memory Segmets. Below I created a little program, I commented near each line the memory sements it saved in my opinion. Please let me know if I understood it correctly or not.

```
public class Person
{
      private int salary; // non-initialize value -> Bss segment
      private int id = 5; // initialize value -> Data Segment.
      private String name = new String("Johani"); // refrence will be saved in data while the object in heap.
      public static int num = 5; // static initialize value -> Data Segment.

      public void myFunc()
      {
             int i = 10; // Stack
             String myString = new String("abcd"); // refernce in Stack, while object in heap.
      }
}
```

If I have some mistakes, please let me know.

Comment: First of all `private int salary;` will be initialized to 0. Besides that what do you need that information for? In general you can say: objects are stored on the heap while primitives/references are stored in their respective scope ( instance fields within an object, static fields within the class object and local variables/parameters on the stack).

Comment: "BSS" and "data" are not part of the Java memory model.  You should just forget about them when writing in Java or in any other language that targets the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

Comment: As an aside, don't use the `name = new String("Johani")`. `name = "Johani"` is prefered.

Comment: I think you are trying to tie the Java Virtual Machine with the underlying physical memory structure. This can't be done because your program may run on a veriety of physical machines. As the other respondents have pointed out.